# does upgrading .net framework changes Server Setting?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I need to upgrade .net framework in my Prod Server.earlier 3.5 is installed and I need to install 4.5.
By installing the .net framework (4.5.1)  Does it update any operating system settings?  Will it change how the server runs?

Comment: This question might be better answered over here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Simple answer: no. Complicated answer: it depends.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your reply.will it change how server behaves,including IIS setting and all?

Answer (score 1):

3.5 runs on a different CLR than 4.0/4.5/4.5.1, so you should be alright. The story would be different for a 4.0 to 4.5 upgrade.

If truly unsure, you could try testing everything in a VM first.